# How to pass data from NOT same origin tabs consoles with Chrome and Javascript?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

I am executing scripts using Chrome Developer Tools console on two websites. On first website script gathers data, and on the second website another script takes these data, and puts it in a form.

Websites use different domains. Currently I am manually copying result from script one, and paste it into script two as a input data. But this takes too much time.

How to pass data from console of first website to console of second website programatically knowing they are NOT same origin?

Comment: Why do this via the console?  Why not write a script to do this?

Comment: Google "Web scraping techniques with JavaScript"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd recommend using a userscript instead. Set the userscript to run on both pages, and use [`GM.setValue`](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM.setValue) to save the data on the first page, then use `GM.getValue` to retrieve the data on the second page. For example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name             New Userscript
// @include          /^https://stackoverflow.com/
// @include          /^https://example.com/
// @grant            GM.setValue
// @grant            GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==

if (window.location.host === 'stackoverflow.com') {
  GM.setValue('data', 'foo'); // .catch the Promise here if you want
  // after the data is saved, you could also redirect automatically if you want:
  // window.location.href = 'example.com'
} else {
  GM.getValue('data')
    .then((result) => {
      console.log(result);
    });
    // .catch the Promise here if you want
}
```

Result, after going to Stack Overflow and then to example.com:

[image]

You'll need a userscript manager like [Tampermonkey](https://www.tampermonkey.net/).

No more copying-and-pasting necessary - just write the userscript code *once* to automatically scrape, save, and possibly redirect to the new page and populate it as well.

Comment: Superb. Thank you, I will try it!